# No signing certificate matching team ID "<ID>" with a private key was found

Tags: ios, xcode

My builds started breaking today, seemingly for no reason. The only change I made that I can think that would affect this was when I ran the app locally and changed the signing method to automatic.

I reverted this change, but the errors still persist. I can still build fine locally, but everything fails in bitrise.

Anyone got any idea what could be causing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason xcode had wiped the team associated with the provisioning profile in the .pbxproj file. Reverting it to a really old version got it building again, not sure why reverting it to the state where the latest successful build was didn't work though.